# Convert elapsed time a decimal in Oracle

Tags: oracle

When performing the below calculation (end_time minus start_time) in Oracle you get a result of +00 01:30:00.000000.  How can that result be converted to 1.50?

```
to_timestamp(to_char(end_time,'HH:MI AM'), 'HH:MI AM') - 
to_timestamp(to_char(start_time,'HH:MI AM'), 'HH:MI AM')
```

Comment: do you mean add 20 minutes?

Comment: Basically I need to convert the result of the calculation to a decimal so 1 hour and 30 mins would be equal to 1.5

Comment: What data type are `start_time` and `end_time`?  `varchar2`?  `date`?  `timestamp`?  `timestamp with local time zone`?

Comment: timestamp is the data type.

Comment: OK.  Then why are you converting the `timestamp` values to strings and then back to timestamps?  Are you trying to ignore the day, second, and millisecond components of the `start_time` and `end_time`?

Comment: Yes in this case I was ignoring the day, second and millisecond components.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
select dat,extract(hour from dat) ||'.'||trunc(100*extract(minute from dat)/60,0) result from
(select to_timestamp('04:30 AM', 'HH:MI AM') - to_timestamp('03:10 AM', 'HH:MI AM') as dat from dual union all
select to_timestamp('02:30 AM', 'HH:MI AM') - to_timestamp('02:00 AM', 'HH:MI AM') as dat from dual)
```

Results:

```
DAT                                               RESULT                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+00 01:20:00.000000                                1.33                  
+00 00:30:00.000000                                0.50
```

Answer (score 1):

[The difference between two `TIMESTAMP`s is an `INTERVAL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#g196492). You can easily extract the various components and obtain the desired result with some arithmetics. In the general case (for a result in fractional *days*!):

```
with testdata as (
    select NUMTODSINTERVAL(1.55,'DAY') i from dual
)

select EXTRACT(DAY FROM i) 
       + EXTRACT(HOUR FROM i)/24 
       + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM i)/(24*60)
       + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM i)/(24*60*60)
FROM testdata
```

---

In your particular case, assuming (1) *"timestamp is the data type"* (2) you're *"ignoring the day, second and millisecond components"* (3) you want fractional *hours* :

```
select ...
   EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (end_time-start_time)) 
   + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (end_time-start_time))/(60)
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method: since your times are only accurate to the minute you may as well just use DATEs, subtraction of which yields a decimal number, e.g.:

```
to_date(to_char(end_time,'HH24:MI'), 'HH24:MI') - 
to_date(to_char(start_time,'HH24:MI'), 'HH24:MI')
```

If the date portions are guaranteed to be on the same date, you can use an even simpler expression for the same result:

```
end_time - start_time
```